# Does the equivalence principle hint at the quantization of gravity?

Tags: physics, quantum-physics

So I've been pondering about the [equivalence principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87889/equivalence-principle-and-acceleration-vs-a-gravitational-field):

"Einstein came to realise the principle of equivalence, and it states that an accelerated system is (locally) completely physically equivalent to a system inside a gravitational field."

But if I think about an [Einstein like thought experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%27s_thought_experiments#Falling_painters_and_accelerating_elevators) where he drops say a particle in an elevator and realizes locally within the elevator both acceleration and gravity produce the same effect.

[image]

If we presume the particle is in superposition of position then we can go a step further we can measure the standard deviation of acceleration. Note, standard deviation is strictly a quantum mechanical property (when experimental error is removed)! So the standard deviation caused by [acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) (one can define this via the Heisenberg picture) is the same as that caused by gravity by the equivalence principle.

Also to talk about acceleration and locality (position) simultaneously the operators of position and acceleration simultaneously the operators must commute (which does happen to be the case in flat space-time).

Are there any philosophers who argue that the equivalence principle hints at the quantization of gravity? (I've presented the quantum mechanical argument as opposed to the QFT version for ease of discussion)

Comment: Sorry to say, but to me it looks as if you are just mixing up some arbitrary ingredients from physics. Why Heisenberg picture, why commutation of position and acceleration, which role has the standard deviation? In my opinion loop quantum gravity quantizes in a much more direct way the gravitational field: The Ashtekar variables are candidates for starting the formalism of quantization.

Comment: Because you can define acceleration via the Heisenberg picture. Commutation of position and acceleration is required so you can talk about acceleration and locality (/position) in the same sentence.

Comment: Standard deviation is a quantum mechanical property (in classical mechanics this should be 0)

Comment: Physics question

Comment: @armand These types of topics are well explored in philosophy journals as well: https://philpapers.org/rec/DAVQMA

Answer (score 1):

First, "standard deviation" is in no way strictly a property of QM. But more importantly, a valid model of general relativity on the quantum scale does not yet exist; before you can make your argument, you first need quantum gravity.

BTW there's a Nobel prize in it for you if you *can* successfully combine QM with GR.

Comment: "standard deviation" is in no way strictly a property of QM - In the context of the experiment I've given where I've barred experimental error can you give an example of another source of standard deviation?

Comment: Also this kind of argument could be made against the equivalence principle in Einstein's era when he suggested something different from Newtonian Mechanics. But then the counter would be "before you can make your argument, you first need Non-Newtonian gravity." That isn't  how science usually works

Comment: @MoreAnonymous I do not fully understand the context of your experiment. Regarding your second comment, are you a scientist? Because GR reduces automatically to newtonian dynamics in the limit of low speeds (compared to light) and small masses (smaller than a black hole). In the case of GR, then, it *contains* newtonian dynamics as a special case, which is exactly how science works.

Comment: Feel free to ask for a clarification about the experiment then? Yes I do happen to be trained in physics. My point was historically the equivalence principle came first and then was rightly extended beyond the Newtonian framework. In fact Einstein made predictions (beyond the Newtonian framework) with the equivalence principle alone as well before the completion of GR